# .Net5 Core API: In Post action, Dictionary object is not received in [FromForm] but received in [FromBody]

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, .net-5

I have two actions

```
        [HttpPost("MyFromForm")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> MyFromForm([FromForm] RequestExample request)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(request);
        }

        [HttpPost("MyFromBody")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> MyFromBody([FromBody] RequestExample request)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(request);
        }
```

The class contains only one property of Dictionary type

```
    public class RequestExample
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> DeviceDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

**Request**
[image]

```
{
  "deviceDetails": {
    "additionalProp1": "string",
    "additionalProp2": "string",
    "additionalProp3": "string"
  }
}
```

In case I send the data using swagger to these methods, The method having FromBody is working but the method having FromForm is not working.

*Using: FromBody*, I am able to receive the dictionary in the request
[image]

*Using: FromForm*, I am **not** able to receive the dictionary in the request
[image]

**Question:** Why I am not able to receive the object in FromForm type of request?

Comment: You didn't show how you send data to MyFromForm (screenshot shows only MyFromBody)

Comment: @Evk I have updated the post with curl requests.

Comment: @GurpreetKailey did you manage to get an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you didn't change the Request body type. The `FromForm` attribute is for incoming data from a submitted form sent by the content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` while the `FromBody` will parse the model the default way, which in most cases are sent by the `content-type application/json`, from the request body. [Read this for more](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/).  Try to change it, And its better to use Postman.

[image]

Comment: I am using Curl request as following.||                                                                                                      curl -X POST "http://localhost:7002/MyItems/MyFromForm" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "KeyValuePairs={
  "additionalProp1": "string",
  "additionalProp2": "string",
  "additionalProp3": "string"
}"

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending valid X FORM URL ENCODED data:

And example is this:

```
curl -d "additionalProp1=nice&additionalProp2=woohoo" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://localhost:7002/Abc/MyFromForm
```

you are trying to send a json string as a form dictionary.

Form enconded values should be separated by ampersands without quotes on the keys or values.

Also using multipart/form-data is not to send form data, at least not generally speaking.  multipart/form-data is used to upload files or binary data not text fields.

You should use **-d instead of -F** and **Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded** instead of **multipart/form-data**

Answer (score 0):

Due to passing through a JSON do the following: Change

```
  [HttpPost("MyFromForm")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyFromForm([FromForm] RequestExample request)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult(request);
    }
```

to

```
  [HttpPost("MyFromForm")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyFromForm([FromBody] RequestExample request)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult(request);
    }
```